# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 while running on xampp

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have just created a project using CLI, running following command

```
Laravel new testProj
```

In **routes** folder in **web.php** file I added few lines

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    return 'Test Server';
});
```

**The problem is**

When I am using **localhost/testProj/public/** it is showing me welcome page but when I change this url to **localhost/testProj/public/test** it gives an error stating **NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161**.

Now, when I execute a command on CLI **php artisan serve** and browse same page using **localhost:8000/test** it shows desired page.

Laravel version is 5.3.22